# Send single backslash in text to keyword in RobotFramework

Tags: escaping, robotframework

**(Answered) - Editted:**
I was trying to use RF to send `'sed'` command to a remote host. I am concatenating test with arguments (vars) tu build the `'sed'` command and only needed to escape the `('/')` character, as it was the delimiter of the `'sed'` command.

---

**Original question:**
I am trying to pass a variable to a keyword that has backslash `('\')`. I do that in order to escape a special character.
When I am sending with one backslash `('\')` the keyword receives with no backslash.
When I am sending with two consequent backslash `('\\')` the keyword receives with two backslash chars.

**Example:**

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test send text to keyword
    Example keyword
    ...    text_arg1=text\<with\>backslash
    ...    text_arg2=text\\<with\\>backslash

*** Keywords ***
Example keyword
    [Arguments]  ${text_arg1}  ${text_arg2}
    Log  Log1: ${text_arg1}
    Log  Log2: ${text_arg2}
```

**Example result:**

```
Log: text<with>backslash
Log2: text\\<with\\>backslash
```

**Expected result:**

```
Log: text\<with\>backslash
```

Comment: I have copy-pasted your code this is the output `Log2: text\<with\>backslash`. What Robot Framework version do you use? Here is all about [escaping](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#escaping) in RF

Comment: Actually, you are correct. I have defined the question incorrectly. I need it to use in a 'sed' command and didn't need to escape the `'<'` and `'>'` chars at all. There was a `'/'` though I did need to escape.
I have posted the question because when building the 'sed' command, the backslashes were used and I didn't achieve the expected results.
BTW, I use RF version 3.2.2
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Should I delete this question?

Comment: What you have put into your previous comment and into the question, you could put that into an answer instead. You can answer your own question and you can accept it as well. Generally I am glad when someone finds out the issue and comes back to post is as an answer. You can never know when will it be useful for someone else.